# Use of inclusion/exclusion when determining the groups of a given order

Tags: group-theory, inclusion-exclusion, sylow-theory

In my group theory class, when we are asked questions like

> Determine the groups of order 30

or

> Prove no group of order 90 is simple

We can do this, using a combination of Sylow's theorems and a bunch of little tricks. One of the tricks that comes up again and again involves the principle of inclusion/exclusion. I don't quite get it, though.

Given a group of order 30, we know there are either 1 or 6 Sylow 5-subgroups and 1 or 10 Sylow 3-subgroups. If we assume there to be both 6 5-subgroups and 10 3-subgroups simultaneously, we run into a problem. That's because the Sylow p-subgroups for a given p intersect on the identity, so we can easily say there are 6 * 4 = 24 elements of order 5 and 10 * 2 elements of order 3. That's too many elements.

The problem I have is when the Sylow p-subgroups are of prime powered order. For example, in the answer to the second question above we see the following argument:

> if we pick two distinct Sylow 3-subgroups K1 , K2 , then |K1 ∩ K2 | =
>   1 or 3, so |K1 ∪ K2 | ≥ 9 + 9 − 3 = 15 and K1 ∪ K2 \ {1} consists of
>   elements of orders 3 or 9. Thus G has at least 14 elements of order 3
>   or 9.

What is in the intersection of K1 and K2? Why are we we taking the union of just two elements? Why does their union consist of elements of order 3 and 9? If we took a case where the Sylow 3-subgroups had order 27 instead of 9, how would we proceed? Is there a situation where we need to take a union or 3 or more groups and use the more general inclusion/exclusion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: K1 and K2 are subgroups, so there are group elements inside them. They are Sylow 3-subgroups, so in fact each one has 9 elements inside it, most of them of order 3 or 9, but 1 of order 1. The intersection of K1 and K2 is another subgroup. It definitely has the identity in it, but it could conceivably have two other elements in it.

Comment: Ah ok, because the intersection of groups is groups. I remember that. So if we had k1 and k2 of order 27 say, we could say their intersection would have at least elements of order 1, 3, 9, and 27? That is, at least 4 elements. Then their union would have at least 27 + 27 - 4 elements?